# SSL_connect() and SSL_accept() calls

Tags: c++, c, ssl, encryption, openssl

I have been struggling with this for a few days now figuring out how they work. I have read the documentation and looked at some examples but I am still in need of guidance.

Specifically, when the client calls `connect()` and successfully connects to the server host, should I issue the `SSL_connect()` right after it to Initiate the handshake ? The client then tries to write some bytes to the socket using `SSL_write()`.

On the other hand, the server uses `pselect()` to monitor any read fds ready for read and issues the `accept()` call successfully for the incoming connection. Should I issue the `SSL_accept()` call right after the accept() returns to complete the handshake ?

I have noticed that the `SSL_connect()` returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (this is when the SSL_connect() is issued after a select() call to monitor the write fd set and returns and as per the Openssl documentation).

What is the right procedure here on issuing the calls and in what order ?

Edit to add snippet of code -

```
Client side :
          err = connect(fd, addr, addrlen);

          if ( err == -1 && errno == EINPROGRESS )
          {
              // check if this is a true error,
              // or wait until connect times out
              fd_set fdset;
              FD_ZERO(&fdset);
              FD_SET(sfd, &fdset);
              timeval tv =  {F_sockwaitconnect, 0};                                                   TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(err = select(fd + 1,\
                                NULL,\
                                &fdset,\
                                NULL,\
                                &tv));

                  // what happened?
                  if ( err == 1 )
                  { 
                      connect was successful
                  }
                  else
                     return 0;

            const SSL_METHOD *method;
            SSL_CTX *cctx;
            SSL *cssl;

            FILE *fp;
            fp = stdout;

            ERR_clear_error();

            method = TLSv1_client_method(); 
            cctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   

            if ( cctx == NULL )
            {
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
                return 0;
            }

         SSL_CTX_set_verify(cctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
         SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(cctx, 4);
         if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(cctx, "mycert.pem", NULL) == 0)  
              return 0;                   

         SSL_CTX_set_options(cctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);

         ERR_clear_error();

         cssl = SSL_new(cctx);   /* create new SSL connection state */
         SSL_set_fd(cssl, fd);   * attach the socket descriptor */

         ERR_clear_error();
         int rconnect = SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ;
         while ( rconnect == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ || rconnect == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE )
         {
             char *buf = (char *) malloc(124);
             ERR_error_string(SSL_get_error(cssl, rconnect), buf);
             ERR_clear_error();
             if ( rconnect == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ ) {    
                 int err = 0;
                 fd_set fdset;
                 FD_ZERO(&fdset);
                 FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
                 timeval tv =  {F_sockwaitconnect, 0};
                 TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(err1 = select(fd + 1,\
                                                  &fdset,\
                                                  NULL,\
                                                    NULL,\
                                                    &tv));
                  // what happened?
                  if ( err == 1 )
                  {                   
                      rconnect = SSL_connect(cssl);   
                   }
               }
            }
            X509 *cert;
            cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(cssl);
            char line[2000+1];
            if ( cert != NULL )
            {
              X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), line, MAX_SIZE);
              X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), line1, MAX_SIZE);
              X509_free(cert);
            }

            ERR_clear_error();
            r = SSL_write(cssl, buffer, len);
            < check error >


Server side :
    int res = pselect(max_fd + 1,   // host socket file descriptor
                      &fd_setw,      // set of ds wait 4 incoming data
                      NULL,          // no write operations
                      NULL,          // no exception operations
                      &tm,           // how much time to wait
                      &sig_set);     // block all signals
     if ( event on listening socket )
     {
          client = accept(sfd, &peer, &peerl);  
     }
     else       // incoming data to receive on existing connection
     {
          SSL *ssl;
          FILE *fp = stdout;
          if ( !ctx )
          {
              return 0;
          }

           ERR_clear_error();

           ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
           SSL_set_fd(ssl, soc);

           int ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
           while (ret <= 0) {
              ERR_print_errors_fp(fp);
              char *buf = (char *) malloc(124);
              ERR_error_string(SSL_get_error(ssl, ret), buf);
              ERR_clear_error();
              ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
            }

            X509 *cert;
            cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
            char line[2000+1];
            if ( cert != NULL )
            {
               X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), line, MAX_SIZE);
               X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), line1, MAX_SIZE);
               X509_free(cert);
             }
             // get data and analyze result
             int rc = 0;
             bool recv_called = false;           
             rc = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, len);
             < check error >
     }
```

Before all the above, the server opens, binds and listens on a non-blocking socket for any new incoming client connections.

When I run the above, the client does the connect() and the server does the accept(). 
The server is now waiting at pselect() for any fd's to be ready to receive data. 
The client on the other hand is at the SSL_connect() and keeps getting the SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ error. The select() returns the socket is ready to read. 
My guess is the client is waiting for the SSL_accept() part of the  handshake ?  I do not know why the server is waiting at pselect(). The code around SSL_accept() is wrong i.e it loops and does not look for the WANT_READ and WANT_WRITE errors but I do not get to that point in the code.

Comment: is your client code synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @RichardHodges  All the sockets are non-blocking. The client writes out all the I/O vectors 1 by 1 in a loop and can come back later if not all data was written. Does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 4):

`SSL_connect` can be called whenever the `connect` is finished. Since both `connect` and `SSL_connect` need to exchange data with the peer they might not succeed immediately when using non-blocking sockets. If `SSL_connect` returns with an error of `SSL_WANT_READ` or `SSL_WANT_WRITE` you have to call it again after new data got available on the socket (`SSL_WANT_READ`) or the socket is writable (`SSL_WANT_WRITE`). You can check or wait for this with `select`, `pselect`, `poll`, epoll, kqueue or whatever API your OS provides for this.

`SSL_accept` and `accept` are similar, i.e. `SSL_accept` can be called directly after a successful `accept`, might not succeed immediately since data exchange is needed with the SSL client and thus you have to call it again if it returns an error of `SSL_WANT_READ` or `SSL_WANT_WRITE`.

Note that `SSL_write` and `SSL_read` might also result in such errors. i.e. you need to deal with  `SSL_WANT_READ` and `SSL_WANT_WRITE` also for these functions and also the same way as with `SSL_connect` and `SSL_accept`. It might even be that a `SSL_read` results in a `SSL_WANT_WRITE` since a SSL renegotiation might happen even if the SSL session was already established.

Comment: Thanks. The client does the connect() and issues a select() if the connect is not successful to wait for the socket to be writable. Once that succeeds, I issue the SSL_connect() call. This returns back with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. At this point the socket is writable but for some reason the SSL_connect() returns back a WANT_READ error. I am not sure why. At first guess I thought it was because the SSL_accept() call should have happened by now to complete the handshake. Is that true ? If so, should I loop in client around the SSL_connect() till the SSL_accept() finishes ?

Comment: @PeterJ: As I said, both `SSL_connect` and `SSL_accept` need to exchange data with the peer. This is not only send some data but actually receive data too - have a look at [how the SSL handshake works](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660a.gif). Given that you are using non-blocking sockets the `SSL_connect` will not (blocking) wait for the server to reply but give you `SSL_WANT_READ` so you can call it again once the server has send the reply back.

Comment: @PeterJ: "...should I loop ..."* - the main point of using non-blocking sockets is to do other things in the mean time. If you don't want to do this use blocking sockets instead. Busy looping is just wasting resources, i.e. is much worse then just using a blocking socket where the OS kernel can deal with other things until the peer replies. If you use non-blocking sockets to have control over timeouts use `select` or similar to wait for the socket readable (in case of `SSL_WANT_READ`) and use a timeout for this function - but don't just blindly retry again and again inside a loop.

Comment: I changed the code a bit. Once the client does the connect() and the server accept() the connection, the client needs to send a few bytes over. Before the SSL_write(), I do a SSL_connect() and get the WANT_READ error. I do select() to wait for the fd to be readable. This hangs! The server on the other hand is waiting on pselect() to wait for any fd's to be ready to recv the bytes which will only happen after the client sends them. Then the code  would do the SSL_accept() to complete the handshake and then SSL_read(). I am doing something wrong in the server code and not getting to SSL_accept()

Comment: Per the picture you shared, does the SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ error on SSL_connect() suggest that the client is waiting for the server to send over the handshake details (via SSL_accept() ) ?

Comment: @PeterJ: From my understanding of the short description of the code in the comment it should work. But, it is unclear if my understanding of your code matches what the code actually does, i.e. please provide the actual code. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just added snippet of code for client and server. I also state what happens when I run the code at the bottom. Hope it helps.

Comment: The `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` return value means that you should re-try the operation either when the socket becomes readable or when the SSL connection's state may have changed. (Be careful, unlike a TCP connection, an SSL connection only has one state.) If `SSL_connect()` returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` that likely means that the client's `SSL_accept` data hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: @PeterJ: `rconnect = SSL_connect(cssl)` - `SSL_connect` does not return the error code as you assume here. And you don't actually check what kind of error `SSL_accept` returns but just blindly assume that it is non-fatal and you just can retry. Please make sure that a retry is actually what need to be done. Also there is no such thing as `soc` as in `SSL_set_fd(ssl, soc);`, it's likely `client`. Please make sure that your example code actually is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. It makes no sense to look for problems if the actually used code is different as it seems to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks. Making changes and will let you know. Also, the soc in SSL_set_fd() is really the socket returned by accept(). So that should be OK.

Comment: Still working on changes. I did have a question while I make those changes - Should I call SSL_connect() and SSL_accept() right after the client does the connect() and server does the accept() or only when I know I am writing data (client) and receiving data (server).  And, if the client sends data multiple times over the same connection, should the SSL_connect() and SSL_accept() happen just 1 time or each time the data is to be sent/received ?

Comment: @PeterJ: `SSL_connect` and `SSL_accept` are called at the **beginning** of **each** TLS connection since they handle the TLS handshake. They are called before doing any read or write of application data, i.e. right after the successful `connect` or `accept`. With non-blocking sockets they are called until they succeed or permanently fail.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks. I made more changes and now running into some hangs. The problem I have is the client and server can go thru the same code to do reads and writes. So I need to know if its the client or server doing the `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` because it needs the right SSL structure to be passed in. Is there a way to test and get a SSL structure from a file descriptor ? So after we do `SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd)`, is there a way to retrieve `ssl` from a known `fd` ? That `ssl` was used in `SSL_accept()` and `SSL_connect()` so it has to be the same for `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()`.

Comment: I noticed there is a `SSL_get_fd()` function that would return the `fd` for a `ssl` context. Is there a reverse of that function i.e return `ssl` structure for a passed in `fd` ?

Comment: @PeterJ: Not that I know of and I don't think that it would make much sense either. The ssl handling needs to know where to send to and recv from the data (i.e. the fd) but the fd does not care if is is associated with anything which processes the data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I do have the `fd`. I dont have the `ssl` structure that was used in `SSL_accept()` and `SSL_connect()` however. I lose it along the way. Can I just re-generate a new SSL structure using `SSL_new(ctx)` and then use `SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd)` since I know the `fd` ? Would it be the same as using the original ssl structure that was used in `SSL_connect()` and/or `SSL_accept()` ?

Comment: @PeterJ: No, the SSL structure contains the current SSL state. If you just create a new SSL structure it is not valid for the expected state of the connection. Just don't loose your SSL structure.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Okay. Im thinking about creating some kind of lookup for `fd <-->ssl structure`. The code is too complicated to keep track of and not lose the `ssl structure` unfortunately.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I wanted to get back to you on this and let you know that it looks much better now and seems to be working. I basically did a lookup table for fd <--> ssl structure. Now anywhere in the code, if I have the file descriptor, I can get to the corresponding ssl structure for the SSL operations.